# BizTalk WCF-WebHttp - Send header value from the orchestration variable

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, orchestration, biztalk-2016

In my BizTalk application I have a API call (WCF-WebHttp) for which I need to pass a `sessionid` which is generated from by calling another service. So I have created a WCF-WebHttp send port and it returns the session id to orchestration. Now I need to pass this `sessionid` value from orchestration to a send port (WCF-WebHttp static port) and this `sessionid` will be used in headers of this API call.

I generally configure headers in Outbound http headers in message tab of WCF-webhttp port. But here I can give only static headers. So how can I pass the `sessionid` header to the service (wcf-webhttp static port) with value which I get from orchestration. Do I need to use dynamic ports for this or can I achieve this in static port? How it can be achieved?

Comment: I use a custom WCF End Point Behavior for this sort of thing.  I've done this for various things like Auth headers as well as setting the correct version of TLS.

Comment: But how i can get the value from the orchestration to set the header value here. Is it possible to access promoted property in here or is there anything else

Comment: Create a message only promoted property and set it as you do normally.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below can help

xPathString = System.String.Format("string(/*[local-name()='loginResponse' and namespace-uri()='urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com']/*[local-name()='result']/*[local-name()='sessionId']/text())");
sessionId = xpath(LoginResponse.parameters, xPathString);

APIMUrl = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

SalesforceCallBackRequest(WCF.HttpMethodAndUrl) = "POST";
SalesforceCallBackRequest(WCF.HttpHeaders) = "Content-Type:application/json" + System.Environment.NewLine +"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + System.Environment.NewLine +"Authorization: Bearer " + sessionId;

SalesforceCallBackRequest(WCF.BindingType) = "basicHttpBinding";
SalesforceCallBackRequest(WCF.SecurityMode) = "Transport";

Port_APIM(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = APIMUrl;
Port_APIM(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "WCF-BasicHttp";

Answer (score 0):

Try with MessageOutput(WCF.HttpHeaders) or MessageOutput(HTTP.InboundHttpHeaders) or something similar. I succeded to do that some months ago but now I don't remember which method was exactly. Anyway it will return a value as string and then you should parse that string to retrieve the header that you want